# How do I decode events of a transaction from the transaction receipt?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

On Etherscan it shows Swap, Remove Liq, Transfer, migrate etc... How do I decode this information from a TransactionReceipt using web3 API?

Currently, I see patterns on Liq removal such as a Null Address in the logs. Is this the way etherscan does it or is there a way to extract method type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called *event signature* in Solidity terminology. The event log first 4 bytes match the hash of an event ABI descriptor.

To decode, you need to have the ABI files of the events you are decoding. With the ABI file, you can decode the rest of the event data and convert it to human-readable info.

[More here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12951/620).

Comment: thanks. turns out i was using bep20 general abi, needed to use pancake abi. the catch now is to make sure what happens when pancake swap is no longer the most popular swap. hopefully there's a solid protocol for abis so we don't have to store new ones everytime

Comment: one general question though, if ther is at least one SWAP event, then it is safe to assume the entire transaction is a swap?

Comment: One transaction can contain 0 - n swaps.